# Can "when" also be used with "that"?

Tags: conjunctions, optional-that

> There was a time when my brothers played with me that I felt unhappy.

Is this sentence grammatically legal? I know the sentence would be more concise if it was just "There was a time when my brothers played with me". The "that I felt unhappy" seems erroneous or too much, but is there anyone who might be able to say if it could be correct?

Comment: The sentence might be grammatically legal, but it doesn't feel pleasant. And leaving out "that" makes it a lot harder to read.

Comment: I think the reason why it feels unpleasant is because our brains immediately abbreviate the "when my brothers played with me" and read it as ... "There was a time that I felt unhappy", which doesn't seem to go well. It seems like we should use "when" instead of "that"

Comment: Now I'm not sure what you want any more. Do you want to remove all of "that I felt unhappy"? Doing that would turn it into a different sentence! Oh, just replacing the word "that" with "when" _also_ turns it into a different sentence.

Comment: Right. I'm just curious to know if the first sentence "There was a time when my brothers played with me that I felt unhappy" is grammatically legal, to which you think it would be OK.

I was commenting on how the "that..." feels overdoing it. I did not mean to actually cut that part of the sentence out to make it a sentence.

Comment: @HeyDoeFarm. With your construction with 'that' it sounds like you felt unhappy when your brothers played with you. This could be interpreted as something very  nasty happening (even abuse). When you use 'when' instead of 'that' it is clear that your brothers played with you when you felt unhappy, probably to cheer you up.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an ambiguity with respect to **time** and an ambiguity whether the *that*-clause is supplemental or restrictive which makes that statement seem not very well articulated.  Does **time** refer to a stage of existence or a particular occasion? That ambiguity in turn makes **when** ambiguous. Does it mean **whenever**?  And should **played** be **were playing**? Does the verb refer to a particular incident or to the general state of affairs?

> There was a time that I felt unhappy when(ever) my brothers played with me.

Let's say that they always liked to rough-house and you were the youngest sibling who ended up getting battered and bruised. At this stage in your young life, it was never fun to play with them.

> There was a time when my brothers were playing with me that I felt unhappy.

On this one occasion my brothers were playing with me and I felt sad. I felt no joy that day.

It's not really possible to know what you're trying to say.

Comment: Thank you. What I meant was that time is supposed to refer to a period. 

I really like the first sentence construction. Initially, I was doubtful of it because I wasn't sure if we could have "time" and "that" in the same sentence. But just to be certain, I can say "time that I felt unhappy", instead of "time when I felt unhappy when my brothers played with me" because this would create 2 whens.

Comment: 2 "whens" would not work right? "that...+when..." would be OK though right?

Comment: The reason a second "when" would not work is because it introduces ambiguity: "my brothers played with me when I felt unhappy" can mean my brothers played with me because I was unhappy!

Comment: @HeyDoeFarm:  I think then that you should say **whenever** and reverse the order of the  *when*-clause and the *that*-clause, as I have it in my first example.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing of your example sentence aside, there is nothing wrong with using the pronoun *that* in relationship to time. As a pronoun, it can apply to anything specific.

> That was a very special time.

You can use multiple *whens* and multiple *thats*:

> Singing that song was that person's specialty.
>   There was a time when I knew when to avoid such things.

Any issues around the use of *when* and *that* in your sentence are not due to their singular, repeated, or mixed use per se, but other syntactical and semantic concerns.

---

As said elsewhere, the sentence, as you have it, is a bit ambiguous.

Consider the following:

> 1. There was a time in my life when my brothers played with me whenever I felt unhappy.
> 2. There was this time a while back when my brothers played with me, yet I remained unhappy.
> 3. There was this time when my brothers played with me because I was unhappy.
> 4. One time, when I wanted to be left alone, my bothers played with me and this made me unhappy.

You need to determine what you're trying to say and then clearly phrase it to express that meaning.